# If-Then Loop in R not Recognizing Conditional Statement

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks something like the following:

```
X Y
1 3
1 7
1 9
2 12
2 4
2 8 
3 11
3 3
3 5
```

I'd like to create a new variable Z that = 0.25 if X = 1, 0.75 if X = 2 and 0.95 if X = 3.

I've tried the following code, which creates a variable Z and then loops over X, checking to see if X is a certain value, and then sets Z to the corresponding correct value. For example:

```
data$Z <- 0
for (i in 1:length(data$X)){
   if (data$X[i]==1) {data$Z <- 0.25)
   if (data$X[i]==2) {data$Z <- 0.50)
   if (data$X[i]==2) {data$Z <- 0.95)
}
```

The problem is that for some reason the conditional trigger isn't getting tripped in this code. If I just run it with the first if statement, *all* of the Z's are set to 0.25. With just the first two, they're all 0.50, etc.

Any clue as to what's happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this simple example, the easiest way would be to use subsetting:

```
data$Z <- 0.25
data$Z[data$X==2] <- 0.50
data$Z[data$X==3] <- 0.95
```

No need for any loops or if/else statements.

Comment: I don't see how this would be "better". It saves a few characters in the code, ...

Answer (score 4):

Use `ifelse` here beacause it is vectorized:

```
transform(dat, Z=ifelse(X==1,0.25,ifelse(X==2,0.75,0.95)))
 X  Y    Z
1 1  3 0.25
2 1  7 0.25
3 1  9 0.25
4 2 12 0.75
5 2  4 0.75
6 2  8 0.75
7 3 11 0.95
8 3  3 0.95
9 3  5 0.95
```

PS: here I assume that X take only 3 values.

**EDIT**

I like using sql case for such manipulations. You keep clear the business logic and it is fast as a vectorize version( intuitions)

```
library(sqldf)
dat$newX <- sqldf('SELECT CASE X 
       WHEN 1  THEN 0.25
       WHEN 2 THEN 0.5
       ELSE 0.95
       END AS newX
      FROM dat ')
```

Answer (score 4):

All these answers so far assume that you've only 3 values (and rightly so, there is no reason to assume otherwise).

However, assuming that you might have more than 3 values, you can use `merge` in that case as so:

```
# assuming this is your data (dummy)
set.seed(45)
df <- data.frame(x=rep(1:5, each=5), y=sample(25))
```

Here, you've five unique values for `x`. You can create a `data.frame` with the values you want to generate an additional column for each value of X as:

```
# here for each unique x, there is a value (just for example, randomly generated)
# equivalent to 0.25, 0.5 and 0.95 in your case
key <- data.frame(x=1:5, val=runif(5))
```

Now, you can use `merge` as:

```
merge(df, key, by="x", all=T)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to set Z to the value you want *at the same indexes* where x meets those conditions, so:

```
data$Z <- 0
for (i in 1:length(data$X)){
   if (data$X[i]==1) {data$Z[i] <- 0.25)
   if (data$X[i]==2) {data$Z[i] <- 0.50)
   if (data$X[i]==3) {data$Z[i] <- 0.95)
}
```

Comment: Who has two thumbs and feels dumb? This guy.

Comment: @EpiGrad This is the least idiomatic answer. Learn to use vectorized functions instead of `for` loops. Your code will run much faster that way.

Comment: Yeah, I don't fully understand the R community's general hatred for `for` loops, but I do tend to think that things like `ifelse` are better for these cases, I was mostly just correcting the specific flaw in OP's original code.

Comment: There is no general hatred, but this loop is extremely inefficient. But I see your point of correcting the specific flaw and that's why I didn't downvote.

Comment: @Roland In this case, because of the specific problem I'm dealing with, the speed gained by vectorization is not work the time it will take laying out something like ifelse appropriately. Here is one place where I'm not willing to sacrifice clarity for speed measured in tiny units.

Comment: It just hurts if beginners use `for` loops for such a task ... And if you don't understand my answer immediately, you should go back to reading an introduction to R.

Comment: Try out the `for` loop approach with a matrix with 10^6 rows and you might reconsider accepting a vectorized approach instead...

Comment: @DanielFischer And when dealing with a 10^6 matrix, I will use a vectorized approach. And we have handy answers for those, which I've upvoted. But since I'm not working on a 10^6 matrix, I'm not particularly upset.

Comment: @Roland I understand your answer just fine. Considering switching my accepted answer to it, but honestly, the optimization argument isn't getting much traction with me for this problem, because the limiting factor is human neurons in processing that this task is finished.

Comment: @EpiGrad, there are many ways to answer a question (in most circumstances). As the OP, you are allowed to choose the best answer that **you think** answered your question. Of course you're allowed to be influenced by the community (from votes/comments), and in general, the community gets it right. There's nothing particularly wrong with this solution. It'll give you the answer. It is just inefficient. And as such, the community members point it out.

Comment: @Arun Thanks. I decided to switch the answer because Roland's is a decent balance of vectorized speed and clarity (unlike some of the day, one line solutions, which fall into a trap I find vexing in R to end up with really opaque one liners). Though if I could upvote Marius twice for finding what I was doing wrong and pointing out that specific issue, I would. Time saved reminding me that things need references > time saved on vectorized solutions.

Comment: Yes, my (+1) to @Marius is for the same reason that he took the time to find out what you did wrong.

Comment: This is the most accurate answer to the OP.  The comments about performance are interesting but should not detract from this answer correcting the specific issue.

Answer (score 3):

It works with just one `ifelse` command:

```
transform(dat, Z = ifelse(X == 3, 0.95, 0.25 + 0.5 * (X - 1)))

  X  Y    Z
1 1  3 0.25
2 1  7 0.25
3 1  9 0.25
4 2 12 0.75
5 2  4 0.75
6 2  8 0.75
7 3 11 0.95
8 3  3 0.95
9 3  5 0.95
```

It even works without any `ifelse` (thanks to mathematics):

```
transform(dat, Z = 0.25 + round(0.50 * (X - 1) ^ .48, 2))

  X  Y    Z
1 1  3 0.25
2 1  7 0.25
3 1  9 0.25
4 2 12 0.75
5 2  4 0.75
6 2  8 0.75
7 3 11 0.95
8 3  3 0.95
9 3  5 0.95
```

Comment: +1! I like the X-1 trick ! even we loose the logic (we hide the business rule)!